# Why might TControl.Hide not hide a control?

Tags: delphi, components, visibility

Is there any reason whatsoever, no matter *how* trivial it may seem, that would stop `TControl.Hide` or `control.Visible := False` from working?

I have one line of code for my application that is to hide a panel that contains some controls (JvPanels etc.) that for some reason doesn't hide the panel.

This is the code

```
pnlMainData.Hide;
```

I've tried sending direct messages to the panel to hide it (as is in the SetVisible function) to no avail.

Comment: Perhaps `pnlMainData` is not what you think it is? Perhaps `pnlMainData` has a parent that manages its child controls automatically? Perhaps you do `pnlMainData.Show` in the `OnTimer` event of a `TTimer`, or in the `OnIdle` event of a `TApplicationEvents`?

Comment: Does ShowWindow(pnlMainData.Handle, SW_HIDE) hide the panel? If yes then maybe a custom WndProc is eating certain messages?

Comment: How about you show a small project that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well after fighting with this for a while, i re-did a stack of code to approach the Hiding event and sorted it out myself.   One thing i did notice too is that this problem sometimes occurs when using FASTMM and when not using it seems to work fine.

Ive sent the app to be tested now by my customers testers so we'll see if they have the same problem.

Comment: Don't kid yourself that FastMM is the problem. The problem is almost certainly in your code.

Comment: Im not.  I used fastmm to track down some other bugs i was tracking and just noticed that when trying to hide the panel it would sometimes fail to hide it.  never the less, the hide functionality is working as it should.